# Extending core types without modifying prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

How does one extend core JavaScript types (String, Date, etc.) without modifying their prototypes?  For example, suppose I wanted to make a derived string class with some convenience methods:

```js
function MyString() { }
MyString.prototype = new String();
MyString.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};
var s = new MyString("Foobar"); // Hmm, where do we use the argument?
s.reverse();
// Chrome - TypeError: String.prototype.toString is not generic
// Firefox - TypeError: String.prototype.toString called on incompatible Object
```

The error seems to originate from String base methods, probably "split" in this case, since its methods are being applied to some non-string object.  But if we can't apply the to non-string objects then can we really reuse them automatically?

**[Edit]**

Obviously my attempt is flawed in many ways but I think it demonstrates my intent.  After some thinking, it seems that we can't reuse any of the String prototype object's functions without explicitly calling them on a String.

Is it possible to extend core types as such?

Comment: Just extend `String.prototype` using `defineProperty` and make sure to set enumerable to `false` and configurable to `true`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**2 years later:** mutating anything in global scope is a terrible idea

**Original:**

There being something "wrong" with extending native prototypes is FUD in ES5 browsers.

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "my_method", {
  value: function _my_method() { ... },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writeable: true
});
```

However if you have to support ES3 browsers then there are problems with people using `for ... in` loops on strings.

My opinion is that you can change native prototypes and should stop using any *poorly written code that breaks*

Comment: +1 for understanding my intent and concerns and teaching me something new!  Extending the prototype is the easiest way, I'm glad to see that there is a safe, standards-based way to do it.

Comment: @maerics Just to make this clear. You must set `configurable: true`. If you do not do this then we can't remove your extension from the prototype when we _need to_. and that is really frustrating. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141210/how-do-i-undo-a-object-defineproperty-call)

Comment: This is not the best idea. A. This does not answer *the question* B. If you extend the prototype of native objects, it is your code that will be the "poorly written code that breaks". Overriding native methods is the worst idea, I've run into this first hand, don't make the same mistake I did. Its safe enough if other projects don't depend on yours, but as soon as you release your code, it pollutes a new namespace. This is bad for the same reason global variables are bad.

Comment: @BT agreed. mutating anything in global scope is a terrible idea

Comment: @Raynos Why is mutating the global scope a terrible idea? can you help me understand this? I see alot of people saying it's a bad idea, it leaves room for more questions than answers, or sometimes you hear (deprecated bad idea) I mean the why is just as important as to the what.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Even this code does not fully extend the native `String` type (the `length` property does not work).

Imo it's probably not worth it to follow this approach. There are too many things to consider and you have to invest too much time to ensure that it fully works (*if* it does at all). [@Raynos provides another interesting approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141734/extending-core-types-without-modifying-prototype/7141932#7141932).

Nevertheless here is the idea:

---

It seems that you cannot call `String.prototype.toString` on anything else than a real string. You could **override** this method:

```
// constructor
function MyString(s) {
    String.call(this, s); // call the "parent" constructor
    this.s_ = s;
}

// create a new empty prototype to *not* override the original one
tmp = function(){};
tmp.prototype = String.prototype;
MyString.prototype = new tmp();
MyString.prototype.constructor = MyString;

// new method
MyString.prototype.reverse = function() {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

// override 
MyString.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.s_;
};

MyString.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.s_;
};


var s = new MyString("Foobar");
alert(s.reverse());
```

As you see, I also had to override `valueOf` to make it work.

**But:** I don't know whether these are the only methods you have to override and for other built-in types you might have to override other methods. A good start would be to take the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and have a look at the specification of the methods.

E.g. the second step in the `String.prototype.split` algorithm is:

> Let *S* be the result of calling ToString, giving it the **this** value as its argument.

If an object is passed to `ToString`, then it basically calls the `toString` method of this object. And that is why it works when we override `toString`.

**Update:** What does **not work** is `s.length`. So although you might be able to make the *methods* work, other properties seem to be more tricky.

Comment: Also, it means that instances of *MyString* will be objects, not primitives, so may have peculiar behaviour if used as if it were a primitive.

Comment: Not perfect, but one of the best answers. Now, you could use a special getter for `.length` and a proxy for character access like `str[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in this code:

```
MyString.prototype = String.prototype;   
MyString.prototype.reverse = function() {
    this.split('').reverse().join('');
};
```

the variables `MyString.prototype` and `String.prototype` are both referencing the same object!  Assigning to one is assigning to the other.  When you dropped a `reverse` method into `MyString.prototype` you were also writing it to `String.prototype`.  So try this:

```
MyString.prototype = String.prototype;   
MyString.prototype.charAt = function () {alert("Haha");}
var s = new MyString();
s.charAt(4);
"dog".charAt(3);
```

The last two lines *both* alert because their prototypes are the same object.  You really did extend `String.prototype`.

Now about your error.  You called `reverse` on your `MyString` object.  Where is this method defined?  In the prototype, which is the same as `String.prototype`.  You overwrote `reverse`.  What is the first thing it does?  It calls `split` on the target object.  Now the thing is, in order for `String.prototype.split` to work it has to call `String.prototype.toString`.  For example:

```
var s = new MyString();
if (s.split("")) {alert("Hi");}
```

This code generates an error:

```
TypeError: String.prototype.toString is not generic
```

What this means is that `String.prototype.toString` uses the internal representation of a string to do its thing (namely returning its internal primitive string), and *cannot be applied to arbitrary target objects that share the string prototype*.  So when you called `split`, the implementation of split said "oh my target is not a string, let me call `toString`," but then `toString` said "my target is not a string and I'm not generic" so it threw the `TypeError`.

If you want to learn more about generics in JavaScript, you can see [this MDN section on Array and String generics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_javascript_1.6#Array_and_String_generics).

As for getting this to work without the error, see Alxandr's answer.

As for extending the exact *built-in types* like `String` and `Date` and so on without changing their prototypes, you really don't, without creating wrappers or delegates or subclasses.  But then this won't allow the syntax like

```
d1.itervalTo(d2)
```

where `d1` and `d2` are instances of the built-in `Date` class whose prototype you *did not extend*. :-)  JavaScript uses prototype chains for this kind of method call syntax.  It just does.  Excellent question though... but is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my question to address these issues (I'll annotate it as such).

Comment: Nah, mine doesn't work either. I just tried to explain that this is the way it would be done if you in fact **could** extend the string-object. But because the functions on the string-object runs on internal representations of string, this is not possible.

Comment: @maerics: I've updated my answer to give a clear answer to your updated question, and not just a theoretical one.

Comment: @Alxandr I think you are right that it can't be done.  Prototypes just _are_ the means for "extension" in JS.  Felix King has some interesting approaches in his answer, though, but ultimately you gotta have a new class if you refuse to add to the built-in's prototpye.

Answer (score 0):

You got only one part wrong here. MyString.prototype shouldn't be String.prototype, it should be like this:

```
function MyString(s) { }
MyString.prototype = new String();
MyString.prototype.reverse = function() {
  this.split('').reverse().join('');
};
var s = new MyString("Foobar");
s.reverse();
```

#### [Edit]

To answer your question in a better way, no it should not be possible.
If you take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor it explains that you can't change the type on bools, ints and strings, thus they cannot be "subclassed".

Comment: Well, yeah, I think so. But, however, I don't think you will be able to extend the string-object like that though. Cause, you can't set the "this" object to equal a string. So I think you'll have tough luck extending the string object. But if you could, this would be the js-way to do it.

Comment: Except that your code throws the same errors.  Anyway, it shouldn't matter since an instance of a String will have the String prototype anyway; it's just saving an extra hop up the prototype chain, right?

Comment: No, well, when you change MyString.prototype, you will thus change the string-prototype too.

Comment: In FF I still get the error `String.prototype.toString called on incompatible Object`. And anyways, you are not doing anything with `s`.

Comment: Well, neither were you. And as said, I don't think you will be able to extend the String-object without modifying it's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic answer is you probably can't. What you can do is what Sugar.js does - create an object-like object and extend from that:

http://sugarjs.com/

Sugar.js is all about native object extensions, and they do *not* extend Object.prototype.