# Javascript Error when using regexp - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript

So I am going through this book and copied the code word for word to be hands on with it and I am getting "Object doesn't support this property or method".

```
var text = '<html><body bgcolor=blue><p>' + '<This is <b>BOLD<\/b>!<\/p><\/body><\/html>';

var tags = /[^<>]+|<(\/?)([A-Za-z]+)([^<>]*)>/g;

var a,i;

String.method('entityify', function () {
var character = {
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '&': '&amp;',
    '"': '&quot;'
};

return function() {
    return this.replace( /[<>&"]/g , function(c) {
        return character[c];
    });
};
}());

while((a = tags.exec(text))) {
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
    document.writeln(('// [' + i + '] ' + a[i]).entityify());
}
document.writeln();
}

//Output [0] <html>
//Output [1] 
//Output [2] html
//Output [3] 
//and so on through the loop.
```

I can't seem to make their example work.

**Edit - I found and added the function but still not quite working.

Comment: I am guessing not, I thought it was a build in function since they don't declare it anywhere.

Comment: there isn't a native method called "entityify"

Comment: I edited my original post with that method, but I am still receiving the error. Thoughts?

Comment: What version of what browser on what version of what OS?  And what library defines `String.method(...)`?

Comment: Its IE 8 on windows 7.  I am guessing nothing defines String.method(...) how would I do that? I have this basically just in a blank html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `String.method(...)` function.  If you're trying to add a new function to the String type then try this:

```javascript
String.prototype.entityify = (function () {
  var character = {
    '<':'&lt;',  '>':'&gt;',  '&':'&amp;',  '"':'&quot;'
  };
  return function() {
    return this.replace( /[<>&"]/g , function(c) {
      return character[c];
    });
  };
})();

'<foo & bar>'.entityify(); // => "&lt;foo &amp; bar&gt;"
```

Although, if you plan to make this part of a library then you should *not* assign to the `String.prototype` directly, instead [use `Object.defineProperty(...)` as illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141932/244128).

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! To sum it up thought, why is there no String.method(...) and or how would you end up having one like this book is doing it?

Comment: There is no `String.method(...)` because it is not part of the JavaScript (ECMAScript 262) language.  To make that function you could simply assign to `String.method` a function of two arguments (name, function) which assigns the function to the named property of the String prototype or using `Object.defineProperty(...)` as I described.