# Just curious how to subclass the String object. (prototypically)

Tags: javascript, subclass

I know this is frowned upon, I was just exploring the idea and for the life of me cannot seem to make this work the way I would want it too.

The example should explain all:

```
String.prototype.MyNS = function() {}
String.prototype.MyNS.fooify = function() {
     return this + 'foo!';
 }

var theString = 'Kung';

alert(theString.MyNS.fooify());
```

Of course this simply append the function definition to 'foo' ... adding this() instead doesnt work.

I understand that I have lost context in there but cannot figure out how to cause the original to fire off and give me what I want.
​

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141734/extending-core-types-without-modifying-prototype ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
String.prototype.MyNS = function() {
    var _this = this;
    return {
        fooify: function() {
            return _this + 'foo!';
        }
    };
}
```

See it [in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cftxY/)

Note, as slashingweapon points out, that you will have to call it like so:

```
String.prototype.MyNS().fooify();
```

As far as I know, there's no cross-browser way to do it without having to call `MyNS` as a function.

Comment: But you have to call it like `"whatever".MyNS().fooify();`

Comment: I love it!  I wish I did not have to call it like that but it at least works...thanks!

Comment: Which is correct: `String.prototype.MyNS().fooify()` OR `String.MyNS().fooify()`?  The answer refers to the comment by @slashingweapon, but then refers to a different syntax.

Comment: The second one, check out Peter's jsFiddle.  It's not the perfect option but it's darn near close for making a unique namespace on native objects.  -- theString.MyNS().fooify()  works on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a new `function` (`class` in oo terms) to the `String` `prototype` and it has no access to the actual `String` instance.

You could just add the property directly to the prototype :

```
String.prototype.fooify = function() {
   return this + 'foo!';
}
var theString = 'Kung';
alert(theString.fooify());
```