# Javascript adding methods to String instance

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add methods to a `String` instance, for example

```
x = "123"
x.method = function() { console.log("test") }

x.method()
```

Comment: If you change `x = "123"` by `x = new String("123")` yeah, but it is not good practice.

Comment: Have you consider using the prototype property ? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp

Comment: You could also add it to `String.prototype` if you want the function on all your strings, but like others said, it's not a good practice to modify native object prototypes.

`String.prototype.method = function () { console.log(this); }`

Comment: @lemil77 Please don't suggest w3schools.com.Have a look at this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: There's nothing "not good practice" about extending an *instance*. There is some argument against extending built-in prototypes (though I've never seen any problem extending `String.prototype`), but not individual instances.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant it is not good practice to create string instances in that fashion. As far as I know, you can't use `==`/`===` to compare with primitive strings as the instanced one refers to an Object instance, so you need to call `.toString()` in the instance before doing any comparison: `new String('foo') === 'foo' //false`, `new String('foo').toString() === 'foo' //true` which is not very intuitive.

Comment: Hi @Stillakid, wow didn't know about all those mistakes in W3Schools.com. As mentioned in http://w3fools.com/ there are a few things wrong in other places, but the one I recommended seems to be fine.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: You can use `==` (`new String("abc") == "abc"` is `true`). It's true that, like all object instances, `===` will check for identity, not content.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh thanks, so much time without using lose comparison that I forgot it'd call the internal `ToPrimitive` method of the Object at the 8th step of [#11.9.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings and numbers are autoboxed primitives, meaning that when you perform OO operations on them, they are cast as "String" and "Number" classes but then are immediately unboxed.

Your code evaluates to:

```
x = "123"
(new String(x)).method = function() { console.log("test") }

(new String(x)).method() // Error
```

Your second call is failing because you are dealing with an entirely different String object.  As T.J. stated, you can get around this by making `x` a String object, but this is not a common or recommended practice.

You can extend **all** strings by adding the method to `String.prototype`:

```
x = "123"
String.prototype.method = function() { console.log("test") }

x.method()
```

This call evaluates the same way as `(new String(x)).method()` but since that method exists in the prototype, it will get called.

Comment: And, how to access to string from the function?

Comment: @e-info128 You can use `this` inside the method, which will be the boxed `String` rather than the primitive `string`, but most operations would work the same.  E.g. `String.prototype.parseInt = function () { return parseInt(this); }`

Comment: If you _need_ the primitive string, you could do `this.toString()` inside the function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it. You have to first take the string primitive and make it a string *instance*, though:

```
x = new String("123");
x.method = function() { console.log("test") };

x.method();
```

JavaScript has both string primitives and string instances. In your original code, when you wrote:

```
x.method = ...;
```

...the string primitive was retrieved from the variable `x` and promoted to a string instance, to which you added the method, but since the string *instance* was never stored back to the `x` variable, the method wasn't there when you tried to call it. (Yes, this *is* counter-intuitive.)

By using `new String(...)` in the above, I actually get the string instance and store it in `x`. Then, since it's a proper object, I can add properties to it.

You can also add methods to `String.prototype`, like this:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1);
};

console.log("testing".capitalize()); // "Testing"
```

Some feel this is bad practice. Others say it's exactly why we have prototypical inheritance, so we can use the prototype to enhance things. While I've never seen any problem from people enhancing `String.prototype`, I *have* seem problems when people enhance `Array.prototype` (because people insist on [misuing `for-in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)) and `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define new properties using ECMA5

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "test", {
value: function test() { console.log('test:',this) },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writeable: true
});
```

See the complete answer:
[Extending core types without modifying prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141734/extending-core-types-without-modifying-prototype)