# Access built in javascript objects functionality by inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop

```
// Function to inherit from paren(P) to child(C). 
function inherit(C, P) {
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = P.prototype;
    C.prototype = new F();
    C.uber = P.prototype; // super
    C.prototype.constructor = C; // reset
}

var child = function(arg) {}
inherit(child, String); //Inheriting from String

var oChild = new child("Get my Length");
console.log(oChild.length);  // Gives 0 ????

var oString = new String('Get my Length');
console.log(oString.length);  // Gives 13 .
```

Actually, where i am doing wrong. How can i call String length property from my inherited function?

Comment: You are failing to pass the arguments to the super constructor. Also, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141734/extending-core-types-without-modifying-prototype

Comment: `.length` is not a prototype property.