# Can a member function be added to the Array class in JavaScript without showing up in a for-in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop, extending-classes

In some code I'm working on I created a JavaScript function that is applied solely to Arrays, and I thought I'd try adding it as a member function.

I added it like so:

```
Array.prototype.myfunc = function(a){
    ...
}
```

Which works fine for the most part.  The problem I run into then is with a for-in loop.  It includes that function in the loop.  If I then type in this snippet:

```
var bar, foo = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie'];
for(bar in foo) console.log(foo[bar]);
```

Then the output is along the lines of:

```
alpha
bravo
charlie
function myFunc(a){
    ...
}
```

So is there any way of doing this but avoiding it showing in the for-in loop?

Comment: You can use `Object.defineProperty` but as always, changing the prototype of global objects is *heavily* discouraged.

Comment: Using `for..in` to get an array's content is also discouraged. Use `for..of` instead. See [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/215552)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141734/extending-core-types-without-modifying-prototype

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to create non-enumerable attributes of any object, including arrays. Remember in JavaScript, arrays are just objects with numbers for keys, which is why attributes you add to them come up in a forEach.

Comment: _"which is why attributes you add to them come up in a forEach"_ - That's just plain wrong...

Comment: I think you meant "... in a `for ... in`", not `.forEach()`