# Delete getter on Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have some code where I use getters in an array and I've run into an issue where `delete` isn't deleting the element from the array. I'd like to know if there's a way to get `delete` working.

Here's some toy code that replicates the issue:

```
let x = [];
Object.defineProperty(x, 0, {
  get: function() {
    return;
  }
});
delete x[0];
```

edit: Slicing is actually not an option, it seems, since only the elements themselves and not the getters are copied.

Comment: When you use a getter, there's no actual `0` property in the array, so there's nothing to delete.

Comment: You're actually removing the getter

Comment: So how would I remove the getter then? `delete x[0]` doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: I did some playing around, basically for an object like that, `delete` turns whatever index into undefined instead of removing it like how `splice` does.. `splice` works for plain out arrays and `delete` for `{entity: instance}` sorta objects

Comment: i just learned one of js's technicalities thanks to this.. it was quite helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the property with the `configurable: true` option. Then you can delete it and the getter will be removed.

```js
let x = [];
Object.defineProperty(x, 0, {
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {
    return "fake value";
  }
});
console.log(x[0]);
delete x[0];
console.log(x[0]);
```

See [How do I undo a Object.defineProperty call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141210/how-do-i-undo-a-object-defineproperty-call)

Comment: We should make the words "dynamic" and "fake" synonymous... just kidding, but it gave me a good laugh.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Interesting to note that when defining a getter in an object initializer `configurable` is set to true by default, which would explain why it was working for me elsewhere. Ah javascript.