# howTo remove Object.defineProperty(it, 'log')

Tags: javascript, properties

i defined Property. i modified a answer found here [How do I undo a Object.defineProperty call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141210/how-do-i-undo-a-object-defineproperty-call)

```
Object.defineProperty(it, 'log', {  
  get() {  
    return console.log.bind(console, `[${Date.now()}]`, '');  
 },  
});
console.log(`line of this console log will follow next line`);
```

I don't need it anymore and have been trying to remove it for a while.

so i read here [How do I undo a Object.defineProperty call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141210/how-do-i-undo-a-object-defineproperty-call)

and tried then to delete it like so

```
delete Object.prototype.log;
delete Object.prototype.it;
```

also tried to redefine it as was at the beginning:

```
Object.defineProperty(it, 'log', {
  get() {
    return console.log.bind(console, ``, '');
  },
});
```

with no effect.

and

```
Object.defineProperty(it, 'log', {
  value: "",
  writable: false
});
```

with no effect.

now i always see if i use a

console.log(msg);

below something with `(src/script.js:28:11)`

example results:

`console.log('000000');`
i get
`at Object.<anonymous> (src/script.js:28:11)`

if i use `console.log('000000', '111111');`

```
console.log
    000000 111111

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/script.js:36:11)
```

Comment: can you show the full example code? I don't see how defined is an object "it"

Comment: @Kordrad i cant show full example. I'm not allowed to do that

Answer (score 1):

there is an example of how you can overwrite the object. If the object is not a 'const'

```js
let object1 = {"test": 123};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
  value: 42,
  writable: false
});

object1.property1 = 77;

console.log(object1.property1); // 42

const {property1, ...rest} = object1
object1 = {...rest}
console.log(object1.property1) // undefinded
```

Comment: now woked if i use it so ```
Object.defineProperty(it, 'log', {
  value: "",
  writable: false
});
```